# Looking for a simple way to include profvis output in a Markdown file in R

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

The title pretty much says it all. I want to profile a function in R (with the profvis package) and display the output in an R Markdown file, without manually creating a screenshot and ideally with no additional packages except the ones that are loaded with profvis, e.g. htmlWidgets and htmltools.

To be more specific I imagine something like:

```
library(profvis)
profvis_output <- profvis(rnorm(1e06))
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(profvis_output, "provis_output.html")
```

and then include the thereby created html file in Markdown.

I already tried

```
htmltools::includeHTML("profvis_output.html")
```

in the Markdown file but that did not work.

NOTE: I also want it to be renderable to a PDF

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(profvis)    
```

## profvis

This is an R Markdown document using profvis.

```{r}
profvis({
  data(diamonds, package = "ggplot2")    
  plot(price ~ carat, data = diamonds)
  m <- lm(price ~ carat, data = diamonds)
  abline(m, col = "red")
})
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, it is not possible to render it as a PDF, however. I guess I just have to take a screensshot.

Comment: Or Perhaps you can generate the provis visualization, save it to a file format, and then call that file into Rmarkdown, in hopes of making it more automatable